# Como puedo plantear la siguiente relación entre tablas?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

estoy realizando un proyecto en Laravel y tuve que crear 3 migraciones para tener 3 tablas. La de Productos, Modelos , y Marcas. Pero tenía dos maneras de pensarlas donde la primera era que, Un marca contenía varios modelos y que un modelo tenía un producto. La otra manera era que Un Marca tenía varios Productos y que cada producto tenía un modelo.

Como yo lo plantee en laravel con las relaciones fue de la siguiente manera.

La migración de marcas:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('marcas_productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

La migración de modelos:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('modelo_productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('model');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
            $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('marcas_productos');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

La migración de productos:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('ptype_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('marcas_productos');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('model_id');
        $table->foreign('model_id')->references('id')->on('modelos_productos');
        $table->text('fob')->nullable();
        $table->string('buy_coin');
        $table->string('sale_coin')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('sale_price')->nullable();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->double('quantity')->default('0');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
        $table->string('file')->nullable();
        $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
        $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Pero cuando corro las migraciones obtengo un error de relaciones en la consola.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `marcas_productos`)

  at C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\AXIS\globaltec-vuepanel-master\globaltec-vuepanel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

  1   C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\AXIS\globaltec-vuepanel-master\globaltec-vuepanel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails")

  2   C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\AXIS\globaltec-vuepanel-master\globaltec-vuepanel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

No entiendo porque obtengo el error, si es un error que hice al realizar las relaciones entre tablas.

Comment: ¿En qué orden se ejecutan las migraciones?, además ¿por qué 2 migraciones buscan crear la misma tabla?

Comment: @BetaM Perdon fue un descuido mio ahora edito la pregunta, había copiado mal el código. Y el orden es como esta mostrado, primero marca despues modelo y ultimo producto.